# Regex pattern in c# start with @ and end with 9;

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Need regex pattern that text start with"@" and end with "	";

I tried the below pattern

```
string pattern = "^[@].*?[&#x9;]$";
```

but not working

Answer (score 3):

Since `&#x9;` is an hex code of [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters), why not just using [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) and [`EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) methods instead?

```
if(yourString.StartsWith("@") && yourString.EndsWith("\\t"))
{
    // Pass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This patterns works fine. I have tested it.

```
string pattern = "#(.*?)9";
```

See below link to test it online.

https://regex101.com/r/iR6nP6/1

C#

```
const string str = "dadasd#beetween9ddasdasd";
var match = Regex.Match(str, "#(.*?)9");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex syntaxt, the `[]` denotes a group of characters of which the engine will attempt to match one of. Thus, `[&#x9]` means, *match one of an &, #, x or 9* in no particular order.

If you are after order, which seems you are, you will need to remove the `[]`. Something like so should work: `string pattern = "^@.*?&#x9$";`

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like:

```
string pattern = "^@.*?[ ]$"
```

There are also many fine regex expression helpers on the web. for example https://regex101.com/ It gives a nice explanation of how your text will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You should [use `\t` to match tab character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html)

> You can use special character sequences to put non-printable characters in your regular expression. Use \t to match a tab character (ASCII 0x09)

Try following Regex

```
^\@.*\t\;$
```